# EXTRACTVALUE - XMLType query delay

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have two query with the same explain plain:

```
1) select * from cfm_t_dmp;

2) SELECT CATEGORY_ID,
   STATUS,
   USERNAME,
   VALID_FROM,
   EXTRACTVALUE (
      XMLType (data_definition),
      '/customer/type/permissions/text()'),
   EXTRACTVALUE (
      XMLType (data_definition),
      '/bundle/configuration/permissions/text()'),
   AB_LOCK
FROM cfm_t_dmp
```

The query 1) is executed really fast, the query 2) I don't see results after minutes processing.

The main difference is the extractvalue, I executed the query 2) before and it was fast.

Can I tune the 2) query in any way or this is a DB issue?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the type of the `data_definition` column? If its a CLOB, you may want to try changing it to an XMLTYPE and removing the cast from your select statement.

Comment: Yes it's a CLOB. But the query was working before with the CLOB.

Comment: Working before? What have you changed to make it not work?

Comment: "working"... returning value is some seconds. Maybe the issue can be related with the data CLOB, being stored in a different tablespace.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you mean by 'working before'. Is that before you added the extractvalue? or was the query, in its current state, working and has suddenly stopped working without you making any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is slower because Oracle has to search your XML types on those XPaths. If you have lots of data, or if the XML contents are large, then this is a lot of extra work, and it will slow down the query.

To speed it up: IF the XPaths won't change, and the XML data won't change, you could add an extra column that contains the results of your `EXTRACTVALUE` expressions. Querying for that data would be faster because your query wouldn't need to call `EXTRACTVALUE` (because it would just read the data in the new columns), but this would require that you pre-populate it when you insert or update.

It's also apparently possible to index on XML data in Oracle, though I've never tried this myself: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm Although since you're not testing conditions on the value son those xpaths, I'm not sure if indexing would help here.